# Code not deleteing all record from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I created a delete.php where I want to delete records from three tables called person, address and cv... By getting their ID I want to delete their records how ever the code only deletes all records from the person table and not from address and CV.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// GET ID FROM person_id
// PAK ID VAN person_id 
$person_id = (isset($_GET['person_id']) ? $_GET['person_id'] : null);

// CREATE PREPARE STATMENT FOR DELETING RECORDS FROM person_id
// MAAK EEN STATEMENT OM WAARDES TE VERWIJDEREN VAN person_id
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `person` WHERE person_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $person_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

$address_id = (isset($_GET['address_id']) ? $_GET['address_id'] : null);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `address` WHERE address_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $address_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

$cv_id = (isset($_GET['cv_id']) ? $_GET['cv_id'] : null);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `cv` WHERE cv_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $cv_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}
// AFTER CLICKING DELETE GO TO LINK
// NA HET DRUKKEN VAN DELETE GA NAAR LINK
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/Website/admin.php");

// CLOSE CONNECTION AND STATEMENT
// SLUIT CONNECTIE EN STATEMENT
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

EDIT:

My tables

[image: l]

Comment: I am guessing its because you dont load any value into `$address_id` or `$cv_id`

Comment: I am also guessing if you looked at your `php error log` there would be some error messages telling you that

Comment: Look at the `bind_param()` statements. They use variables `$address_id` and `$cv_id` but nowhere in the code do you create those variables or load any values into them. So the execute probably runs but of course it never finds a row with a key of `NULL` or whatever PHP will generate for a non-existant variable

Comment: Your code expects 3 variables in the query string, so the URL you visit should look like: `delete.php?person_id=X&address_id=Y&cv_id=Z`.  Are all 3 parameters in your URL?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Surely you are not suggesting anybody actually still runs with `register_globals` turned on! **Please say it aint so**

Comment: can you post your schema in sql format?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No ... I'm suggesting the posted code expects 3 variables in the query string.  If they're not there, records won't be deleted.

Comment: @ Don'tPanic, I am wondering how come person_id is deleting all the records in person table while person_address and address_id has a relation and person_cv and cv_id has a relation.

Comment: If the DELETE is not CASCADING then the schema is probably wrong. Please paste your schema for these 3 tables **in SQL format** so we can see what is actually going on here instead of all this **guessing**

Comment: @GLRotterdam maybe you want to use PDO's for MySQL-Handling? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059 . Just as a Hint ;)

Comment: @Snickbrack `mysqli` should be just fine. `PDO` I agree is a better API but changing that in itself is not going to magically solve anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly have you seen my last sentence? `"...Just as a Hint ;)"`. And PDO makes everything a little bit more clear to understand. And you don't have these `?` in your SQL-String which can be confusing with more than 2-3 Positions...

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting from those 2 tables based on the address id and cvid  if I understand your table structure correctly you should be deleting based on person ID from all 3 tables.

Comment: Yes that's actually what I want but it doesn't work... In my database I do have person_cv connected to cv_id and person_address to address_id having both delete on cascade.But even then they are not deleted

Comment: You had better show us your schema so we can see what is linked to what

Comment: right - I was under the impression the address table and cv table would have the same person_ID as the persons table (parent child relationship) thus delete from the persons, address, and cv table should all be linked with the one common key (primary and foreign respectively) person_ID. If that's not the case then yes - as Riggs put it, we should probably get a look at your schema.

Comment: See EDIT ill add more pictures

Comment: _I was under the impression the address table and cv table would have the same person_ID as the persons table_ Well you should know you created the database or at least you have the ability to check that that is tha case. But if that is the case then your DELETE queries are wrong as they dont use `person_ID` they use `$address_id` or `$cv_id`

Comment: I wasn't the OP Riggs so no I have no way of knowing that table structure.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the understanding I get from your table structure, you should have a person_id in the address table and the CV table respectively.

This means that, you should delete from the address and the CV tables based on the person_id

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// GET ID FROM person_id
// PAK ID VAN person_id 
$person_id = (isset($_GET['person_id']) ? $_GET['person_id'] : null);

// CREATE PREPARE STATMENT FOR DELETING RECORDS FROM person_id
// MAAK EEN STATEMENT OM WAARDES TE VERWIJDEREN VAN person_id
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `person` WHERE person_id = ?'); 
$stmt->bind_param('s', $person_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

$address_id = (isset($_GET['address_id']) ? $_GET['address_id'] : null);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `address` WHERE person_id = ?');



$stmt->bind_param('s', $address_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

$cv_id = (isset($_GET['cv_id']) ? $_GET['cv_id'] : null);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM `cv` WHERE person_id = ?'); 

$stmt->bind_param('s', $cv_id);                                         

// EXECUTE STATEMENT AND IF RESULT IS FALSE SHOW ERROR
// VOER STATEMENT UIT EN ALS VALS IS GEEF ERROR AAN
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}
// AFTER CLICKING DELETE GO TO LINK
// NA HET DRUKKEN VAN DELETE GA NAAR LINK
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/Website/admin.php");

// CLOSE CONNECTION AND STATEMENT
// SLUIT CONNECTIE EN STATEMENT
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

It would be great if you actually make person_id a foreign key on the address and CV tables. You may not necessarily need to write a different delete for the two tables (CV and address)